# How to make my characters block the field's view?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I'm working with a project in C# and Unity and I'm having trouble with visibility. I want only my character to be visible when he is on top of a cube (number). I am creating a 3D board game. This is what it looks like. [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x4YC.png). What I want is when my characters step on those numbers, the numbers will not show through my characters, just like in real life, they will be blocked by my character.

Comment: so you probably need a collider that checks for intersections of your character towards a cube.

Comment: If the number is on the cube your character will block it. If the number is UI then by default it wont as the number is near the camera.

Comment: If the digital is a UI camera, it is difficult to avoid the display of the digital

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are UI, you can try this line of thinking
In order to facilitate the demonstration, first select the 2D perspective, then create the root node Canvas, name it Menu, and create the sub UI that needs to be displayed under the Menu. Here I create three images of different colors as different UI interfaces, named RedUI and BlueUI respectively. , GreenUI, and finally create the button corresponding to the control, the 01 button shows red, 02 shows blue, and 03 shows green. There can only be one UI in the scene. (The UI when actually making the game will be more complicated, and the logic of how to control it will be more, but the principle is the same as this method. For the convenience of demonstration, the UI layout is relatively simple)
After the UI is created, the three-color UI is hidden by checking the component panel, leaving a scene with only buttons. We try not to rely on the display control of external options, and hide the UI before the game starts. Everything is done through code. control.

[image]

Create a script, name UIManager, and start writing our code:

```
      public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
      {
      //Define three GameObject classes to represent three UI interfaces
        public GameObject UIRed;
        public GameObject UIBlue;
        public GameObject UIGreen;
        void Start()
        {
       Status = UIStatus.Red;//Assign Red to the attribute in the start method, so that the red UI interface is displayed at the beginning of the game
        }
        void Update()
       {

       }
       public enum UIStatus//Define enumeration, enumerate three situations of UI display
      {
        Red,
        Blue,
        Green
       }
     private UIStatus uistatus;//Create an enumeration variable
     private UIStatus Status//Define properties to assign values ​​to 
  enumeration variables
 {
     get
     {
        return uistatus;
     }
    set
    {
        uistatus = value;
        UpdateUI();//Call the UI display method after assigning a value to the enum variable to control the display of the UI
     }
  }
   public void UpdateUI()//Define the method of UI display, judged by the value of the enumeration variable
  {
      UIRed.SetActive(uistatus==UIStatus.Red);
      UIBlue.SetActive(uistatus == UIStatus.Blue);
      UIGreen.SetActive(uistatus == UIStatus.Green);
  }
  public void Red()//Method for displaying red UI
  {
     Status = UIStatus.Red;//Assign the attribute Status, and call the UpdateUI method while assigning the value
  }
  public void Blue()//Method for displaying blue UI
 {
      Status = UIStatus.Blue;
 }
   public void Green()//Method for displaying green UI
  {
     Status = UIStatus.Green;
   }
}
```

We drag the script to Menu, and then drag the corresponding sub UI into the script.

[image]

Finally, we add click events to the three buttons, drag the Menu to them, and select the corresponding display method.

[image]

Hope it helps you thank you